# How to control the framerate in KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

How can I control the rendering loop frame rate in KineticJS? The docs for Kinetic.Animation show a frame rate being passed to the render callback, and Kinetic.Tween seems to have no frame rate logic, but I don't see anyway to force, say, a 30fps when 60fps is possible.

Loads of context for the curious follows, but the question is that simple. If anyone reads on, other advice is welcome. If you already know the answer, don't waste your time reading on!

I'm developing a music app that combines some DOM-based GUI controls (current iteration using jQuery Mobile) and Canvas-based GUI controls (using KineticJS). The latter involve some animation. Because the animated elements are triggered by music playback, I'm using Kinetic.Tween to avoid the complexity of remembering how long a given note has been playing (which Kinetic.Animation would require doing).

This approach works great at 60fps in Chrome (on a fast machine) but is just slow enough on iOS 6.1 Safari (iPad 2) that manipulating controls while animations are happening gets a little janky. I'm not using WebGL (unless KineticJS or Chrome does this by default for canvas?), and that's not an option when I package for native UIWebView.

As I'm getting beyond prototype into wanting to make more committed tech decisions, I see the following options, in order of perceived goodness:

1. Figure out how to cap the frame rate. Because my animations heavily use alpha fades but do not involve motion, I believe I could get away with 20-30fps and look fine. Could also scale this up on faster devices.
2. Don't respond immediately to touch inputs, but add them to a queue which I poll at a constant interval and only use the freshest for things like touchmove. This has no impact on my non-interactive animated elements, but tackles the problem from the other direction, trying to reduce the load of user interaction. This would require making Kinetic controls static and manually tracking touch coordinates (not terrible effort if it actually helped).
3. Rewrite DOM-based GUI to canvas-based (KineticJS); rewrite WebAudio-based engine to HTML5 audio; leverage CocoonJS or Ejecta for GPU-acceleration. This means having to hand-code stuff like file choosers and nav menus and such (bad). Losing WebAudio is pretty serious as it eliminates features like DSP effects and very fine-grained, low-latency timing (which is working just fine on an iPad 2).
4. Rewrite the app to separate DOM based GUI and WebAudio from Canvas-based elements, leverage CocoonJS. I'm not sure if/how well this works out, but the fact that CocoonJS passes JavaScript code as strings between the 2 components makes me very skittish about how solid this idea is. It's probably doable, but best case I'm very tied to CocoonJS moving forwards. I don't like architecting this way, but maybe it's not as bad as it sounds?
5. Make animations less juicy. This is least good not because of its design impact but because, as it is, I'm only animating ~20 simple shapes at any time in my central view component, however they include transparency and span an area ~1000x300. Other components like sliders are similarly bare-bones. In other words, it's not very juicy right now.
6. Overcome severe allergy to Objective-C; forget about the browser, Android, and that other mobile OS. Have a fast app that performs natively and has shiny Apple-approved widgets. My biggest problem with this approach is not wanting to be stuck in Objective-C reality for years, skillset-wise. I just don't like it.
7. Buy an iPad 3 or later. Since I already am pretending Android doesn't exist (I don't have any devices to test), why not pretend no one still has iPad 2? I think this is passing the buck -- if I can get acceptable performance on iPad 2, I will feel confident about the app's performance as I add more features.

I may be overlooking options or otherwise naive about how to tackle this. Some would say what I'm trying to build is just silly. But it's working *pretty well* just not ready for prime time on the iPad 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can control the Kinetic.Animation framerate**

The Kinetic.Animation sends in a frame object which has a frame.time property.

That `.time` is a running timer that you can use to throttle your animation speed.

Here's an example that throttles the Kinetic.Animation:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Hn3cC/

```
var lastTime;
var frameDelay=1000;

  var loop = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {

      var time = frame.time

      if(!lastTime){lastTime=time;}

      var elapsed = time-lastTime;

      if(elapsed>=frameDelay){

          // frameDelay has expired, so animate stuff now

          // set lastTime for the next loop 
          lastTime=time;

      }
  }, layer);

loop.start();
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this approach. The problem is this rules out using Tween instead of Animation, and the former is a *lot* simpler code for me since I'm getting note events at various times and displaying "impulse" events that fade over a fixed time (like 0.5s). Using Animation means that view component suddenly needs to hang on to all these note objects with their start times, which is ugly. But, it is doable and probably better than #2-7 above.

Comment: As I think about this being possibly the only option, I'm wondering about interactive components like my sliders. Right now they are draggable=true. How would I throttle this? If I implemented the dragging myself, don't I still need to draw the hit layer on every mouse/touch move to have them function correctly?

Comment: The Kinetic.Tween uses the Kinetic.Animation "behind the scenes".  If your code is heavily invested in the Tween, you could modify the Kinetic.Tween code to throttle the Kinetic.Animation that it uses:  https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Tween.js

Comment: I'm not heavily invested so much as trying to avoid certain types of complexity at this stage. I figured if there was a master setting to throttle framerate, great. But I'll keep this thought in mind. It may be the lesser evil to modify an external library like Kinetic than to have my component track so much state. I guess I can take your word as definitive that there's no better way to throttle Kinect? Basically it has no render loop? If that's the case I'll mark your answer as answering my question.

Comment: Yes, sorry...the Tween currently has no throttling.  One *totally wild hack* that I haven't tried would be doubling the ending values and duration of the tween and then do tween.pause when half the tween duration has elapsed.

Comment: Wait, how would that work? Does the Tween calculate a fixed number of steps?

Comment: Yes the tween calcs the difference between the starting (current) and ending (tweened) values and divides that difference into equal steps--at least for linear easings.

Comment: Here's an attempt at the *totally wild hack* that fires at 30fps by doubling the tween values/duration and then pausing the tween after half the duration:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sj5gw/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49848/discussion-between-jason-boyd-and-marke)

Answer (score 0):

Working from @markE's suggestions, I tried a few things and found a solution. It's ultimately not rocket science, but sharing what I figured out:

First, tried the hack of doubling Tween durations and targets, using a timer to stop them at 50%. This kinda sorta worked but was hard to get to look good and was pretty error prone in coding bogus targets like negative opacity or height or whatnot.

Second, having read the source to Tween and looked at docs again for Animation, decided I could locally use Animation instances instead of Tween instances, and allow the closure scope to hang onto the relevant note properties. Eventually got this working smoothly and finally realized a big Duh! which is that throttling the frame rate of several independently animating things does not in any way throttle the overall frame rate.

Lastly, decided to give my component a render() method that calls itself in a loop with requestAnimationFrame, exits immediately if called before my clamp time, and inside render() I update all objects in the Kinetic canvas and call layer.drawScene(). Because there is now only one animation, this drops frame rate to whatever I need and the app is *fast* on iPad 2 (looks exactly the same to my eyes too).

So Kinetic is still helping for its higher level canvas API, and so far my other control widgets are still easy code using Kinetic to handle user input and dragging, now performing much better as the big beast component is not eating up the CPU.

The short answer to my original question is that no, you can't lock the overall frame rate for very complex animations, but as Mark said, you can for anything that fits in a single Animation instance.

Note that I could have still used Animation without giving it a layer or explicitly calling any draw() methods, but since I'd still have to write all the logic to determine individual element's current visual state, there was no gain to doing this. What would be very useful would be if Tween could accept a parameter to not automatically render. This would simplify code like mine, as I could shorthand the animation on individual objects but still choose when to actually do the heavy lifting of rendering everything. Seeing how much this whole exercise gained in performance on the iPad 2, might be worth adding this option to the framework.

Comment: Actually, what would be very very useful was what I was hoping for, which is Kinetic offering a per-canvas or even per-page setting to throttle the framerate. Basically the code would need to do exactly what I'm doing (though touching a lot more places in the library no doubt). Being able to have multiple canvas instances all locked to the browser's refresh rate or lower is a big win for slower devices.